# Site Collections not appearing in Site Content and Structure View

Tags: site-collection, content-and-structure

I have an odd problem.

When I use the 'Site Content and Structure' feature from the top level site I don't see any of my site collections under the Sites icon.

However I can still open the individual site collections in the 'Site Content and Structure'.

Any suggestions, its really bugging me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected, content and structure only shows the current site collection structure (all lists and libraries in the root collection and all subsites). It has never shown the entirety of the site collections in the farm.